# Socket.io Server-side callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've successfully made a callback with http://socket.io when the client calls the server

```
socket.on('event', function(data, fn){ fn(null, true); }
```

I was wondering if its possible to do the same but this time when the server calls the client?

Comment: I think everthing is explained here -> http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: I've read this page before, it explains how to callback when the client calls the server, not the contrary. I am searching if its possible to do it when the server calls the client.

Comment: do you want to send a function to the client for it to run?

Comment: My goal would be to send an emit event to the client. Once the client executes the function it executes a callback to the server.

Comment: "the function" should that be defined server side or client side? Meaning should the server pass the function itself to the client or is the function defined in the source-code of the client?

Answer (score 1):

The `emit` and `on` works exactly same on both sides: client and server.
So if you emit to client-socket on server side, then if on client-side you are subscribed to that event, it will trigger it. And vice versa.

What you are confused by is that server has one socket that is listening one, and many connections with socket per client.

While client has only one socket to talk to server.

Examples here: http://socket.io/#how-to-use
Do bi-directional messages, and you need to clearly read them before denying that there is no bi-directional messaging.

Comment: This isn't really what he was asking. He's talking about sending callback functions along as an argument to `emit`. The documentation on the website only shows a callback being passed *to* the server where it is executed. He's asking if he can do the reverse and send a callback from the server *to* the client to be executed.

Comment: My bad, I see it now that there was such functionality. Though it is very easy to create yourself for your specific needs.
Would you suggest removing this answer then?

Comment: [I don't know about "very easy".](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1444)